# Qt Licensing for non profit open source software

Tags: licensing, lgpl

I am developing software with a non profit organization and we would like to use the Qt framework to provide a GUI. This will be open source and free for everyone, for ever. Will we need to purchase a commercial Qt license?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [License for open source application based on Qt](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/8105/license-for-open-source-application-based-on-qt)

Comment: The thing I'm concerned about is that this project is being developed under a non profit organization.

Comment: If you are using Qt under the terms of the LGPL (or GPL if you are using Qt's GPL-licensed modules), it is entirely irrelevant that your software is for a non-profit because the LGPL and GPL make no mention of non-profits. In other words, if you are using Qt under the LGPL/GPL, it makes no difference whether you are a for-profit or non-profit entity.

Comment: You can use Qt under the terms of the LGPL (or GPL only if you are using some GPL-only modules). Perhaps you should clarify why you think you will need to purchase a commercial license, so that we could give you more direct answers.

Comment: @Flux Thanks. I'm very happy we can use Qt because it is very powerful. Do you want to add that information as an answer?

Comment: @raging-loon now Flux has clarified that it makes no difference that you're a non-profit, could I ask that you read the linked question again and  let us know if it does, in fact, tell you everything you need to know?

Comment: See also https://opensource.org/osd rules 5 and 6.  An open source license that discriminated against non-profits for some reason, probably wouldn't fulfill this definition.